# Is there k8s annotation for enabling shield protection for ELB (not ALB)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

So my current `.yaml` config includes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: {{ .Values.acm.arn }}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/shield-advanced-protection: 'true' # I need to add this line but for ELB
```

I found this `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/shield-advanced-protection: 'true'` on https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/#shield-advanced-protection but I'm wondering what can I do for ELB.

What I tried is to create this echo service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo-server
          image: jmalloc/echo-server
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    # copied from other service
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:%secret
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/shield-advanced-protection: 'true'
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 80
      targetPort: http-port
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: echo-server
  type: LoadBalancer
```

via `kubectl apply -f echo-service.yaml` and then I can see a new Load Balancer in AWS UI but when I open [Shield](https://console.aws.amazon.com/wafv2/shieldv2#/protected_resources) tab, I can't see anything still.